# symfony form handling subcontroller

Tags: symfony, twig, pimcore

I have a working contactform, which allows the user to send a e-mail to me and additionally gets a confirmation mail.

I would like to add a confirmation message to the page, so the user is sure the message was sent.

**default.html.twig**

```
 <div>
   {% include 'includes/overview.html.twig' %}
   {% include 'includes/service.html.twig' %}
   {% include 'includes/offer.html.twig' %}
   {% include 'includes/aboutus.html.twig' %}
   {% include 'Advanced/contactForm.html.twig' %}
 </div>
```

**contactForm.html.twig**

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 contactfrom nopadding">
{# request has to go further to the contactCormController -> {'request' : app.request} #}
{{ render(controller('AppBundle\\Controller\\ContactFormController::contactForm', {'request' : app.request})) }}
</div>
```

**ContactController.php**

```
public function contactForm(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
    {
        $contactForm = new ContactForm();
        $form = $this->createForm(ContactFormType::class, $contactForm);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted()){ //&& $form->isValid()

            $message = (new \Swift_Message)
                ->setFrom($contactForm->getEmail())
                ->setTo('mail')
                ->setSubject("Kontaktformular - ". $contactForm->getFirstname() ." ". $contactForm->getLastname())
                ->setBody($contactForm->getMessage())
            ;
            if ($contactForm->getHonigtopfRoboter() == "") {

                try {
                    // Sending message to the Host
                    // Sending confirmation message to the user
                    $mailer->send($message);
                    $this->confirmationMail($mailer, $contactForm->getEmail());

                    // empty ContactForm
                    unset($contactForm);
                    unset($form);
                    $contactForm = new ContactForm();

                    $form = $this->createForm(ContactFormType::class, $contactForm);

                    // add succes flashmessage
                    // $this->addFlash('success', 'message');

                }
                catch (\Swift_TransportException $Ste){
                    //TODO: Exception Handling
                    //echo $Ste->getMessage();

                    // add error flashmessage
                    // $this->addFlash('danger', 'message');
                }
            }
            else{

            }
        }
        $contactFormEntity = $form->getData();

        return $this->render('form/contactForm.html.twig',
            ['contactform' => $form->createView()
            ]);
    }
```

1. The most common solution I found was to use "flash message", sadly flash messages only work, if you redirect to a new page. Due to the fact, that my contact form stays on the same page it does not work.
2. My form is embedded and rendered in a sub-html.twig page, so I have the problem to get the information to my **ContentController.php** and further to the page.

I am really stuck and don't really know the best workflow for this scenario. How do i handle the submit and:

1. Success -> empty contact form -> success message on page
2. Error -> leave contact form -> error message on page

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If your form is valid, you should redirect the user after the form submission

```
public function contactForm(Request $request, \Swift_Mailer $mailer)
{
    $form = ...
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $message = ...
        $mailer->send($message);

        $this->addFlash('success', 'Wohoo, we got it!');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('app_contact_form');
    }

    return $this->render('form/contactForm.html.twig', ['contactform' => $form->createView()]);
}
```

Doing this, you don't need to empty the form like you do and then re-create it. And as the user is redirected, he will see the flash message.

Also, always check if the form is valid !

Comment: i would have add a flash message too when there is an error, so that the user understand there is a problem

Comment: Yeah, of course, this was just an example to show how to redirect after form submission :)